# Want to confirm the meaning of the name islice in Python itertools.islice

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm new in Python and I'm not an English native speaker. Today I learned some functions in the itertools module. There is a function called islice. Does it stand for `infinitive slice`? As I understand it can be used to slice infinitive sequence of objects and is commonly used with `itertools.count()`.

Comment: I think it stands for "iterable slice", because it returns a slice from the provided `iterable`

Comment: It isn't always infinite. Depends on the input given https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume it stands for "iterable slice", since it takes the same arguments as the `slice` built-in but generates a sequence of results rather than returning a list.

You may be suffering from some slight misunderstanding of "infinitive," which is a part of speech (in English, "to fall" is the infinitive of the verb "fall"). You perhaps mean "infinite," which is never-ending or uncountable.

If so, you have correctly observed that one advantage of the functions in `itertools` is that they can be applied to infinite sequences. This is because they return iterators that yield results on demand, rather than functions that return lists.

Comment: `islice` returns an *iterator*.

Comment: 'iterable' seems correct: the islice docs use the word. The objects returned by itertools (islice, taskwhile, etc.) are iterators though: generators additionally implement `close(), send()` and `throw()` methods.

Comment: `islice` does indeed return an iterator, and I have modified my answer. The derivation I suggested came from the fact that the main argument is an iterable. islice slices iterables, hence iterable slice.

Answer (score 1):

`slice` is a built-in class.  The prefix 'i' for 'iterator' is added to avoid confusion and a name clash if one does `from itertools import *`.

In Python 2, itertools also had `imap` and `ifilter`, to avoid clashing with the old versions of `map` and `filter`.  In Python 3, `imap` and `ifilter` became the new versions of `map` and `filter` and were hence removed from `itertools`.